# javascript: I want to count words in my textarea it doesn't count words after I press enter key

Tags: javascript

please help me change this countword function to continue counting after i press enter key

```
function countWords(text) {
    var normalizedText = text.
        replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ").
        replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").
        replace("&nbsp;", " ");

    normalizedText = strip(normalizedText);

    var words = normalizedText.split(/\s+/);

    for (var wordIndex = words.length - 1; wordIndex >= 0; wordIndex--) {
        if (words[wordIndex].match(/^([\s\t\r\n]*)$/)) {
            words.splice(wordIndex, 1);
            }
        }

        return (words.length);
    }
```

Comment: Please post HTML and other event handlers you may have set up, like document.onkeydown or such

Answer (score 1):

If the page submits, wrap the fields in `<form></form>`

and have

```
document.querySelector("form").onsubmit=function() { return false }
```

in a script after it